# How to merge element in a list until there are no common character between each elements in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list = `['01', '25', '47', '57']`
how can I iteratively or recursively merge the element until the final list is `['01','2574']`?

Comment: How did you get from the first list to the second?

Comment: I think he means he wants it such that no two elements contain a common digit. Then again, there are many ways this can occur, e.g. `['012574']` has just one element.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the way you derived the second sequence ?

Comment: @101arrowz Since a list is ordered I think there is only one reasonable way to get from the input list to the expected ouptut. Start with the first pair of characters, and always look for the next pair of characters in the remaining list that has a character that matches the last character of the last pair of characters in the output list. If there is a match, concatenate the other character of the matching pair to the last pair of characters of the output, or if there is no match, append the first pair in the remaining list to the output list. Repeat until all pairs are added to the output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `while` loop to keep looking for the next pair of characters in the list that matches the last character in the last string in the output list, concatenate the other character in the pair to the string if a match is found, or append the first string to the output list if there is no match, and remove the matching string or the first string from the input list until the list becomes empty:

```
lst = ['01', '25', '47', '57']
output = []
while lst:
    for i, pair in enumerate(lst):
        if output and output[-1][-1] in pair:
            output[-1] += pair[output[-1][-1] == pair[0]]
            del lst[i]
            break
    else:
        first, *lst = lst
        output.append(first)
```

`output` becomes:

```
['01', '2574']
```